# problem with mac curser changes in sublime text macos

Tags: html, macos, sublimetext

I'm writing html in sublime using macos and the curser changes randomly and I think I pressed something and made it like this but I'm not sure what it is.
image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD0HH.jpg
I want to change curser back to normal but i'm not sure how. Usually i close and reopen sublime to solve the problem but there's probably a better solution I just can't figure it out.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you press the Insert-Key? Maybe you are in the overwrite mode -> https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/enabling-overwrite-mode/1934

Comment: it works! thank you

Comment: Hey there and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add the answer to the question. Instead post an answer below so that it can be properly accepted (if you post it yourself, you will have to wait 2 days counted after you posted your question) which will also mean that the [solved] in the title may remain removed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so thanks to Kiwimanshare I figured it out. It is called overwrite mode and is triggered by option+command+o. here's the link that has the answer https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/enabling-overwrite-mode/1934